# Is there a way to search for multiple strings within a range of cells, and return the range sorted by the first column?

Tags: arrays, string, sorting, search, google-sheets

I'm looking for a way to search within the cells in a range for a specific text value, and have them returned sorted by those values along with the corresponding cell in the next column over. For example, in column A I have the description of the item, and in Column B there is a number value:

[Unsorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPhdP.png)

These describe that particular formats (Col A) and how many of each (Col B). So what I'm looking to do is sort by multiple format, "K-7.75" and "K-20L" for example, and then return that cell along with the corresponding Column B. Is there a way I can write this all in one formula, searching for multiple strings within Col A? Here's what I'd like the output to look like, with the formulas being in A1, A9, and A13:

[Sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmOSF.png)

I know there is a filter option, but I cant seem to use multiple strings in that and I'm looking to eliminate steps in reordering this info. I feel like there's a way to do this with Array and Search or Sort or something, but I'm stuck. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Can you describe or show how would the result be? Do you want to filter by a drop down? Do you want to set one filter on one column?

Comment: Added pics for clarity, thank you for the suggestion. I don't need a drop down, just returned results. And it'd be for both columns, but sorted by values in Col A.

Comment: Do you know in advance the conditions you will get like "k-7.75"? If that is the case you can set every x rows or every x columns the following filter function: =FILTER(A:B, REGEXMATCH(A:A,"K-7.75"))

Comment: @Kessy, that is so close to what I'm looking for, thank you. Is there a way to search for multiple strings with that formula? I know FILTER can use multiple conditions, but when I try to nest, it doesn't seem to want to work. Also, if I understand you correctly, if there is no string return, the function returns NA. I think I'll have to use separate functions, but you've still made my life way easier. Thank you.

Comment: I see, the FILTER function uses plusses (+) instead of commas to handle to OR logic. Like so, =FILTER(A:B, REGEXMATCH(A:A,"K-5.16")+REGEXMATCH(A:A,"K-7.75")). Now all I need is a way to return the values on a different line than the formula itself so i can then select all of it.

Comment: Even easier: =FILTER(A:B, REGEXMATCH(A:A,"K-5.16|1/6|K-20|20L|K-7.75|1/4|K-30|30L")). Using the operator character "|" as an OR logic. Thank you for putting me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks to Kessy:

Do you know in advance the conditions you will get like "k-7.75"? If that is the case you can set every x rows or every x columns the following filter function: =FILTER(A:B, REGEXMATCH(A:A,"K-7.75")) – Kessy

=FILTER(A:B, REGEXMATCH(A:A,"K-5.16|1/6|K-20|20L|K-7.75|1/4|K-30|30L")). Using the operator character "|" as an OR logic. Thank you for putting me on the right track! – MisterSixer